# Temporarily modify the way a counter is displayed in an existing environment

Tags: environments, counters

My document has numbered assumptions 1.1, 1.2, etc. At some point in the text, I would like to define a variant of a previously-stated assumption, say Assumption 1.2, and have its counter display as 1.2b.

I'm trying to achieve that by defining a new `assumptionb` environment that redefines `\theassumption` by grabbing the correct assumption counter value using a label passed as argument, and appending a `b` to it.

Here's my attempt:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]

\usepackage{refcount}  % used to refer to a past assumption by label
\newcounter{assumptionbkup}
\newenvironment{assumptionb}[1]{%
  \setcounter{assumptionbkup}{\value{assumption}}  % save current value of Assumption counter
  \let\oldtheassumption\theassumption  % the current way assumption numbers are displayed
  \setcounterref{assumption}{#1}       % set value of Assumption counter based on reference
  \renewcommand{\theassumption}{{\oldtheassumption}b}
  \begin{assumption}
}{%
  \end{assumption}
  \setcounter{assumption}{\value{assumptionbkup}}  % restore value of Assumption counter
  \let\theassumption\oldtheassumption  % restore how assumption numbers should be displayed
}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.1
  \label{asm:1}
  First assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.2
  \label{asm:2}
  Second assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.3
  \label{asm:3}
  Third assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumptionb}{asm:3}  % should display as Assumption 1.3b
  First variant.
\end{assumptionb}

\end{document}
```

The result is that the variant assumption is displayed as "Assumption 1.2b" regardless of what label I pass as argument to `assumptionb`. Also a ".3" is displayed before the environment:

[image]

The ".3" presumably refers to the argument of `assumptionb` but I don't see why it's being displayed.

I would like the `assumptionb` environment to be friendly with `\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}` so that `\cref{asm:2b}` displays as "Assumption 1.2b" all hyperlinked.

Answer (score 6):

You can manage it in a much simpler way: Just redefine `\theassumption` and nullify the effect of `\refstepcounter` to avoid incrementing the original `assumption` counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{assumptionb}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\theassumption}{\ref*{#1}b}%
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\protect\ref*{#1}b}% Update reference stored
  \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \refstepcounter
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \begin{assumption}
}{%
  \end{assumption}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\begin{assumption}[abc]  % will display as Assumption 1.1
  \label{asm:1}
  First assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.2
  \label{asm:2}
  Second assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.3
  \label{asm:3}
  Third assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumptionb}{asm:3}  % should display as Assumption 1.3b
  \label{asm:b}
  First variant.
\end{assumptionb}

See \ref{asm:b}.

\begin{assumption}  % will display as Assumption 1.4
  \label{asm:4}
  Fourth assumption.
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does it for the numbering. However, `\cref{asm:b}` is displayed as "section 1" for me (even though `\ref{asm:b}` works as in your example.

Comment: I found a working solution by removing the `\renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}`, which appears to be confusing `cleveref`, and saving and restoring the value of the `assumption` counter as in my initial attempt. Not sure if that's the best way to go but it appears to be working.